# Google Tag manager android events not coming back in real

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-tag-manager

I have been doing some test to try to send events from my application to pub/sub or bigquery in real time via firebase sdk and google tag manager.

The function is triggering in real time on the logcat.
[image]

But even though the logcat seem to show real time triggers the data appears in the stackdriver sometimes in real time if not between 5 to 10 minutes after
I am wondering if GTM is not blocking the events to not be send in real time when there is many events coming at the same time and if there is a way to remove that delay.

A more general question will be can we send data from firebase to a real time db using GTM or is it a myth ( I know that there is analytics cloud function for firebase)

Answer (score 0):

The GTM SDKs send traffic in batches to avoid excessive power drain from turning on the cell radio or wifi.